# My beer tastes like green apples.

Tags: beer, bottle-conditioning, off-flavor

I brewed a blonde ale with extract a little over a month ago.  I fermented in primary for three weeks and have been bottle-conditioning for two weeks.  I didn't take an OG, but the final gravity before bottling was 1.011 (exactly what the recipe called for).  I cracked one open this morning to give it a taste, and while it's good, it has a distinct, syrupy taste similar to green apples.  Any ideas what might have caused this?  Is this a taste which will likely mellow out with time?

Comment: Ugh I've had this in 2 of my beers as well, but both of them were kegged. Give it time and hopefully it will mellow out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Green apple flavor is called **Acetaldehyde**. It's one of the off-flavors that can dissipate over time, though it can be caused from a bacteria that won't go away.

I would certainly wait awhile to see if the flavor dissipates.

([Sources here](http://www.mrgoodbeer.com/apple.shtml))

Comment: Yup, give it another month and it should be all right.

Answer (score 1):

Green apple taste can be caused by acetaldehyde, which will generally mellow out over time.  Iirc, it's a middle-compound between sugar and alcohol that the yeast still needs to work on.